# Baggage value not getting printed in log4j2 logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

Iam using log4j2 and sleuth 3.0.3

Below is the confiugration I have used to add a baggage to sleuth

```
spring.sleuth.baggage.remote-fields=sessionId
spring.sleuth.baggage.correlation-fields=sessionId
```

I set the baggage field value from the controller of a request shown below.

```
BaggageField.getByName("sessionId").updateValue("value");
```

I am able to access the value from other points using  `BaggageField.getByName("sessionId").getValue()` and is being propagated to other services but it is not being acessible in the current service where
added the baggage.

the log pattern is

```
 <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%tid] [%t] [%X{sessionId},%X{traceId},%X{spanId}] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
```

Every time I try to print it only traceid and spanid is getting printed leaving session id empty as shown below.

```
[,e5bf8cd9dbf910dc,cb689f3c036b4260]
```

What could be the issue here

Answer (score 0):

This answer has been addressed at

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/2120

where automatically flush to brave keys did the needed trick.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/3.1.1/reference/htmlsingle/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#features-baggage